# htaccess Rewrite to same name file in different folders of site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to search a lot but got no success. I wish that someone could really help me out with this.

Ok, so my website is like:

```
/rewrite.php
/folder1/rewrite.php
/folder2/rewrite.php
/folder1/subfolder1/rewrite.php
/folder1/subfolder2/rewrite.php
```

and so on...

In short, there exist a **rewrite.php** in each and every folder(except admin access folder).

So basically, I want to rewrite to the rewrite.php file in the corresponding directory, but I am not able to do it.

That is

If I request

```
/News
```

then it should rewrite it to:

```
/rewrite.php
```

If I request:

```
/folder1/News
```

then it should rewrite it to:

```
/folder1/rewrite.php
```

and so on for other folders.

Currently, this is what I have in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L,NC]
```

Somewhere, I read that If I remove RewriteBase, then it uses the current directory as RewriteBase. But it failed and didn't worked.

Also, I would like to keep some folders in exceptions(in which Rewriting should be disabled) like:

```
/administration
/config
```

I hope for a feasible solution, if anyone can help me... :)

Best Regards,

Ankur Thakur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(administration|config|rewrite.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(/?[^/]+)$ $1/rewrite.php [L]
```

Comment: Fantastic ! This is exactly what I wanted to do... Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Ok.

Thats working good on my Wamp localhost, but when I tried to run this Live on a web server, its giving me a problem.

When I browse my website, and Open a URL in the Root, say, **/news**, it gives me 404:

Not Found
The requested URL /rewrite.php was not found on this server.

But, when I open a URL in a subfolder, say **/sub2/news**, it opens it very nicely.

So I changed **$1/rewrite.php** to **$1rewrite.php**.

Then, it got reversed. It worked for ROOT URL, but not for **/sub2/news**. It shows the REDIRECT_URL as **/sub2rewrite.php**(with missing slash)

Thanks & plz help.

Comment: @AnkurThakur It's doing what you want. In your question you say when the request is `/news` then rewrite it to `/rewrite.php`. In your live server case, it seems `/rewrite.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: Never mind... But I did a small change and made it to work ;)

Changed it to: (I guess that I made the '/' optional)
**^(.*?)(/?)([^/]+)$ $1$2rewrite.php**

Thanks a lot for your help... :)